# Trouble getting text field value from a dropdown, using an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, oop, webforms

I am trying to change a text field value for a phone number based on what is selected in a drop down for the user's country.

The user should select their country and then either before or after they've typed in their phone number I need the country code to be populated into the phone number text box.

Here is what I have so far, if anyone has any solutions or ways I can get this working I would be very grateful.

NOTE: I have waaay more country codes than listed, but you'll get an idea of the setup with my including just a few.

Thanks!

```
var phoneNum = jQuery('#l_tel').val();
jQuery(function() {
console.log(phoneNum);
var selectValues = {
"AF" : "93 " + phoneNum,
"AX" : "358 " + phoneNum,
"AL" : "355 " + phoneNum,
"DZ" : "213 " + phoneNum,
"AS" : "1 684 " + phoneNum,
"AD" : "376 " + phoneNum,
"AO" : "244 " + phoneNum,
"AI" : "1 264 " + phoneNum,
};

var jPhone = jQuery('#l_tel').val();
var jCountry = jQuery('select.country');
jCountry.change(function() {
    phoneNum = jQuery('#l_tel').val();
    jPhone.empty().append(function() {

    var output = '';
        jQuery.each(selectValues[jCountry.val()], function(key, value) {
            output += key;
        });
        return output;
            });
}).change();
jQuery('select.country').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have take the current number `jQuery('#l_tel').val()` and add the country number `selectValues[jCountry.val()]` to it. Then use `jQuery('#l_tel').val(...)` to set the new number.

You have also to remember the previous selected country number to remove it from the `phoneNum` because otherwise you would end up with the old country number AND the new selected country number.

```
var countryNum;
var jPhone = jQuery('#l_tel');
var jCountry = jQuery('select.country');
jCountry.change(function () {
    var phoneNum = jPhone.val();

    // remove the previous selected country number
    // ^ means that it should only be replaced if the string starts with this number
    if (countryNum) {
        phoneNum = phoneNum.replace(new RegExp("^" + countryNum), "");
    }

    countryNum = selectValues[jCountry.val()];
    var newPhoneNum = countryNum + phoneNum;
    jPhone.val(newPhoneNum);
}).change();
```

note: you have to use `jPhone.val()` to set value of the text field.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uLcxqvxo/

Comment: I'm not sure, but why do you have var countryNum without a value?

Comment: it is set once you call `change()` (last line) anyway

Answer (score 0):

Can be a good start :

**HTML :**

```
<select id="countries">
    <option value="" selected>Choose country...</option> 
    <option value="93">AF</option> 
    <option value="358">AX</option>
    <option value="355">AL</option>
    <option value="213">DZ</option>
    <option value="1 684">AS</option>
    <option value="376">AD</option>
    <option value="244">AO</option>
    <option value="1 264">AI</option>
</select>
<input id="tel" value="" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
$(function() {

    var jSel = $('#countries');
    var jTel = $('#tel');
    var separator = '-';
    var lastPrefix = '';

    // Bind on change event
    jSel.on('change', function() {

        var prefix = '';
        var option = $(this).find(":selected").val();

        if (option != '') {
            prefix = option + separator;
        }

        // get Tel
        var currentTel = jTel.val();

        // check if the tel already contains the separator
        var r = new RegExp(separator,"g");
        if(lastPrefix != '' && currentTel.match(r) != null) {
            currentTel = currentTel.split(separator);
            currentTel.shift();
            currentTel = currentTel.join(separator);
        }

        jTel.val(prefix + currentTel);

        lastPrefix = prefix;
    });

});
```

[Working example on JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z8fe5ovc/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/z8fe5ovc/2/)